# Do I get charged for Azure Managed Disk if the VM is not running?

Tags: azure

The default storage when creating a new VM in Azure is managed disks. In my case I would like to create a failover VM that will be off all the time except when I need it if I need it. Do I pay for the managed disk for the time the VM is not running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will be charged for Azure Managed Disks. It does not matter if the VM or other resources are accessing the storage. You are paying for disk space and the service.

[Managed Disks pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/)

Comment: Thanks. I would have thought that they would move the data to a blob or something similar when the machine was off.

Comment: Think thru what you are suggesting. Why would they migrate your data? That is your job. Image you are a customer with a 1 TB disk and find out that it will take 30 minutes to move the data back and you are charged $0.10 per GB data transfer. Plus you will still be charged for blob storage.